# Touch Screen Clicks Repeatedly on Press - Can't Drag

Tags: touchscreen, xinput, evdev

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS recognizes my touchscreen correctly. Tapping the screen sends the correct ABS coords and BTN_TOUCH.

The problem is that BTN_TOUCH is set to a 1, then immediately set to a 0 even though my finger never leaves the screen. This means that trying to drag something causes hudnreds of "click" events. I've looked through dozens of posts about evdev, xserver, xconfig, etc.

How can I make BTN_TOUCH stay a "1" as long as my finger is held down?!

Answer (score -1):

Installing the touchscreen drivers should solve the problem. Google the touchscreen company followed by "Linux Drivers" and install them.

Comment: The touchscreen is marked as a Advanced Silicon CoolTouch. I have searched by can not find drivers for this device. Is there a multi-touch driver I can use instead of evdev?

Comment: @user301932 I am not sure about that